# Problem accessing IIS hosted site from HTC desire

Tags: android, iis, https, windows-authentication

I'm trying to access a site hosted on IIS from my HTC Desire. The site uses integrated security / windows authentication and uses SSL (with a valid certificate) (It's a SharePoint site if you want to know)

The phone hits the server just fine but is immediately turned away with a 401.2 Unauthorized error. It does not ask for credentials.

I have tried with the default android browser and Opera Mini, but nothing works. It works on an iPhone, but not on HTC devices. We have tried a couple.

Any idea? Or is it just not supported on android devices? It works in all normal browsers on our pc's (IE, Firefox, Chrome etc.)

--
Christian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah found it myself, seems Google just simply didn't implement it in the Android default browser! w00t!

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4962

Ended up installing Fennec (Firefox for android and what not), and it lets me log in just fine. Would have posted a link to it, but haven't got enough points yet it seems.

"*we're sorry, but as a spam prevention mechanism, new users can only post a maximum of one hyperlink. Earn more than 10 reputation to post more hyperlinks.*"

I'm not a spam bot!! :)